# Communication From SQL to Windows Service

Tags: .net, sql-server

I want my database (MS SQL Server) to query my Windows Service (.net). The queries are simple (no objects) and the database and the Windows Service are on the same machine. The queries must be very fast (measured in ms).

I read about WebServices tasks, MSMQ, Service Broker, but I haven't found anything that is simple to implement. Can you help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Server CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) should be easy to configure, you can write a .NET DLL to communicate with your service, and then from SQL Server call the method in your dll to achieve this, assuming you are on SQL Server 2005 and above